# Flutter: Is it possible to click through a PageView?

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to make widgets behind a PageView clickable by wrapping it around a GestureDetector but it doesn't work. Is there another way I can do this?

```
new GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  child: new PageView(
    controller: _pageController,
    children: _buildForegroundPages(),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I believe this is a missing feature I filed [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47119). If you want this feature to be implemented be sure to leave a  reaction.

Comment: Also leave a description of why you want it... it's not at all clear what the use case is here. :-)

Answer (score 20):

Try using the `IgnorePointer` class:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html

> A widget that is invisible during hit testing.

Comment: This doesn't work. It makes the Pageview not scrollable as well.

Comment: Link is not working. It is not very helpful to just provide links without any explanation.

Comment: It worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work like this!

First, wrap the individual children in GestureDetector that you want to interact with.

Second, set the hit test behavior to translucent.

```
PageView(
 ...
 children: [
   FirstChild(), 
   SecondChild(),
   //Child that you want gestures passed down to                  
   GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      child: GesturedThirdChild(),
   ),
  ]
```