# Pass tap event to the child behind in Stack

Tags: flutter

After watching a tutorial video about creating a custom PageView in Flutter, I've come across a problem.
In order to achieve a custom PageView's page positions, I've used a stack of items that swipe left/right depending on the PageView that is placed in a Stack.fill() above every other element in the Stack.

Here's the example of the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
      body: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Material(
                type: MaterialType.transparency,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('InkWell tapped');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$index',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: 4,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want to trigger a Tap event on the InkWell behind the PageView, while still be able to swipe the PageView.

Is it possible to pass the tap event to the element behind the PageView?
Thanks.

---

EDIT:

Since you should not extend widgets in flutter, I've just made a copy of Scrollable class that uses a **HitTestBehavior.translucent** instead of **HitTestBehavior.opaque**. After that you create a copy of PageView using this new Scrollable.

With such modification - the children behind the PageView start receiving gestures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Is it possible to click through a PageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510694/flutter-is-it-possible-to-click-through-a-pageview)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**:

Since you should not extend widgets in flutter, I've just made a copy of Scrollable class that uses a **HitTestBehavior.translucent** instead of **HitTestBehavior.opaque**. After that you create a copy of PageView using this new Scrollable.

With such modification - the children behind the PageView start receiving gestures.

Answer (score 0):

This one is without using a stack,

```
   Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 200.0,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print('InkWell tapped');
                },
                child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: 4,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '$index',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Not an option. Image having 10 InkWells in the stack.

Comment: @Thepeanut well, looks like no solution to your problem in the way you want until now, check these 2 links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510694/flutter-is-it-possible-to-click-through-a-pageview, and this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47119

Comment: Thanks for the Github issue, it has solved the problem :) Changing ScrollableState to use a translucent HitTestBehavior triggers event on events. Now I just need to create a custom PageView that will use a custom Scrollable with a configurable hit test behavior. I will post an answer with the solution when I'm done.

Comment: well good luck with that as I don't know if that is possible (if it was it would've been posted in the issue 2 years ago :) )

Comment: Since you should not extend widgets in flutter, I've just made a copy of Scrollable class with needed modifications. After that you create a copy of PageView using this new Scrollable. And that's pretty much it.

Comment: @Thepeanut then post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transparent_pointer` package to achieve that:

https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_pointer