# How do I allow gestures to pass through a widget in a stack?

Tags: flutter, stack, gesture

please look at the code sample below, or just run it [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/14dbfa70ddfe34ea158860f5aff67f7a)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                  onPressed: () => print('pressed'),
                ),
              ),
              CustomScrollWidget()
            ],
          ),
        ),  
      );
}

class CustomScrollWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: const Center(child: Text('scroll me')),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverFillRemaining(),
        ],
      );
}
```

how do I allow gestures to pass through a widget in a stack?

AFAIK setting the `HitTestBehavior` of a `GestureDetector` only affect the child,
so shouldn't work in a `Stack`, any idea?

please note that the ""solutions"" ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759834/9836706), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538035/9836706)) offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510694/flutter-is-it-possible-to-click-through-a-pageview) do not work

Comment: check out this issue and the comment that presents a workaround, maybe it will help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47119

Comment: yep, same as me

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pretty solution but it does work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              CustomScrollWidget(),
              Center(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                  hoverElevation: 0.0,
                  onPressed: () => print('pressed'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),  
      );
}

class CustomScrollWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: const Center(child: Text('scroll me')),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverFillRemaining(),
        ],
      );
}
```

Comment: except that there's an "invisible" button floating on in the middle of a header
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS3zc.png the button is purely representative the issue is 
the lack of option (AFAIK) to allow a gesture to pass through a solid widget

Comment: in my simulator there wasn't a button visible except when the user hovers over it, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 

Comment: I was hovering it, that's the point, that's not a solution, maybe a workaround, but not one I'd recommend

Comment: if thats disturbing to you you can make the hoverColor transparent, but currently, as you can see here (github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47119), there is no other solution

Comment: firstly yous is not a solution, a workaround at best, second I'm not gonna adopt it or spend any time refining such an approach